# set spinner value to new added value

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I created a spinner that contains book genres.

I made the spinner as follows:

```
staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.Genres_List, R.layout.item_genres );
staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

spiGenres.setAdapter(
        new SpinnerAdapterImplement(
                staticAdapter,
                R.layout.item_genres,
                this ) );
```

`Genre_List` has 30 genres in it.

Now, In the same activity I have an option to read book information from a website and sometimes the genres there are not the ones I have in my `Genre_List`.

My goal is that once the button to read the book information is clicked, to set the spinner with that new genre value.

I tried to do like this:

```
staticAdapter.insert( books.getGenre() ,0 );
staticAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
spiGenres.setId( 0 );
```

But I got an error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

How can I update the spinner to display the new value? (Do I first need to add it to the adapter or can I just set it?)

Thank you

Comment: Reading from the Android ArrayAdapter documentation, UnsupportedOperationException is thrown _if the underlying data collection is immutable_. Therefore, you need to construct your spinner using a mutable ArrayList and you should be able to dynamically update it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, be sure that your list doesn't have any limitation that actually you can add some values to it.

then try use `staticAdapter.add( books.getGenre() );` insted of .insert()

check this link too I Hope it will help you
https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-spinner-add-item-dynamically.html